# Is there an Anglicized transliteration IME for typing Arabic?

Tags: keyboard, ibus, input-language, arabic

In IBus Preferences, Hindi has 5 different IMEs (Input Method Editors), some of which utilize Anglicized transliteration schemes.. ie. they use the Latin alphabet keys on a US keyboard to represent semi-equivalent sounds between the two languages... Chinese has an Anglicized transliteration system called 'pinyin' which is available in IBus...

There is only one Arabic IME which shows up in IBus (I'm using Lucid 10.04).. This Arabic IME uses a native Arabic keyboard layout, which throws me into a spin, as I'm not in any way familiar with the layout, nor the script(yet)... Is there any such thing as an Anglicized IME for Arabic, in any form?.. eg.  A later version of Ubuntu, or in Emacs, etc, or some other specifically-for-Arabic program?

Comment: For those who don't know what this is about: http://www.google.com/transliterate/

Comment: Google transliterate works, so thanks for that and I'm sure some readers will find it useful, but based on my experience with Hindi, google is *too helpful* for my liking... I want to *know* if I've made a typo rather than google double-guessing what I *probably* meant... so I'm really after something I can make mistakes with :) ... Maybe remapping the keyboard would do the trick, if push comes to shove... or maybe just learning the Arabic layout, but that sounds too daunting (initially) that was my experience with hindi...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Buckwalter Arabic transliteration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buckwalter_transliteration) is available in 11.04 at least for Egypt and Syrian Arab Republic keyboard layouts, so go to `Keyboard Preferences > Layouts > Add...` and then pick `Country: Egypt` and `Variants: Arabic Buckwalter`, and give it a try. I don't know if there are regional differences between the same variant in different countries.

Comment: Thanks for this information.. I've not yet tried it, but the Arabic Buckwalter keyboard  is also available in 10.04 (my distro), so I'll comment further on how it goes, when I find out how it all fits together: Country, Keyboard, IBus method, etc, but it certainly look like the right thing.....